# Disable a theme function in from a child theme functions.php in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, themes

I was having a problem with my theme in wordpress, that was showing its own og:meta descriptions on my theme, so it gets duplicated due to all in one seo plugin.

I wanted to disable the ones from the theme, but i did not know how, so i manage to find the function on the php file which is triggering this to show on the website, but i dont know how to disable it from the functions.php or my child theme, so it does not get overriten when update. The function in question is the following

```
// Open Graph Meta
function aurum_wp_head_open_graph_meta() {
 global $post;

 // Only show if open graph meta is allowed
 if ( ! apply_filters( 'aurum_open_graph_meta', true ) ) {
  return;
 }

 // Do not show open graph meta on single posts
 if ( ! is_singular() ) {
  return;
 }

 $image = '';

 if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
  $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'original' );
  $image = esc_attr( $featured_image[0] );
 }

 ?>

 <meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
 <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_title() ); ?>"/>
 <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>"/>
 <meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?>"/>
 <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_excerpt() ); ?>"/>

 <?php if ( '' != $image ) : ?>
 <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $image; ?>"/>
 <?php endif;
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'aurum_wp_head_open_graph_meta', 5 );
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function actually has an inbuilt way of to short-circuit and return early. If the value of `false` is passed to the filter `aurum_open_graph_meta` if will return before any output is created.

```
add_filter( 'aurum_open_graph_meta',  '__return_false' );
```

You can read about the special `__return_false()` function here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_return_false

If this function did not have a early return flag then an alternative method to stop it executing would be removing the action that the function creates. This would be a more universal method that could be applied to most actions registered anywhere in WordPress.

Add your own action that runs **after the action you want removed has been added but before it is executed**.

In this case you can use the `init` hook to make that happen. Inside your action function make a call to `remove_action()` with the details or the hook you want removed.

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_my_action' );
function remove_my_action(){
      remove_action( 'wp_head', 'aurum_wp_head_open_graph_meta', 5 );
}
```

Note that the action needs to be removed on the same `$priority` as it was added (in this case '5'). Try adding the above code to your child theme's functions.php file and see if it removes the action.

If you are only supporting php>5.3 then you could clean up that code by using an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```
add_action( 'init', function() { 
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'aurum_wp_head_open_graph_meta', 5 );
}
```

Some additional reading regarding adding/removing actions in WordPress: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action

Comment: Holly molly.... holly sh..... omg.. you are a star man.. im not really good on php coding and i was reading all those pages which means nothing to me doing test after test and non of it worked... THANKS SO MUCH i owe you a dinner....

Comment: Not a problem, glad that I was able to help you get it sorted. I know the pain of trying things and running test after test without finding a fix so happy I could help get to the solution.